# What is the purpose of the limit in the definition of a differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm currently learning Multivariable Calculus and my textbook gave me the following definition:

A function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at a point $P(x_0,y_0)$ if, for all points $(x,y)$ in a $\delta$ disk around P, we can write $$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)+E(x,y)$$ where the error term $E$ satisfies $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)}\frac{E(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}=0$$ I understand the first part of the definition, but why does the limit in the second part have to be true for the function to be differentiable?

Comment: This definition is saying that a tangent plane has to be "good enough"  in order for a function to be differentiable, and "good enough" is quantified by how fast the error vanishes. $$$$ Notice that in polar coordinates the limit is equivalent to saying $\frac{E}{r} \to 0$. The formula for the gradient in polar coordinates is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{r}$$ If we were to apply the polar coordinates gradient formula, notice that if $E \sim r^a$ for $a<1$, the gradient blows up as we take $r \to 0^+$, i.e. the derivative doesn't exist at the point of tangency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That limit being equal to zero tells you that as the point $(x,y)$ approaches the point $P(x_0,y_0)$, the numerator $E(x,y)$ must approach zero faster than the denominator, where the denominator is just the distance from $(x,y)$ to $P$. This means that the error $E(x,y)$ in the linear approximation provided by the (total) derivative at $P$ is very small near $P$ *even relative to very small distances from $P$*. This is why the derivative provides the "best" linear approximation at $P$, as others pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

It means the linear approximation $\;f(x,y)\approx L(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f'_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$ is the best possible linear approximation, in the sense that
$$f(x,y)-L(x,y)=o\bigl(\|x-x_0,y-y_0)\|\bigr)$$
near $(x_0,y_0)$.